# Translating java to c#

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get lock screen control available for my xamarin media app for android. I have not had much luck with it yet but have been trying to follow this tutorial found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNsELLrZ3V0 . I have most of it implemented into my project but there is one part I'm not sure how to go about when converting their java to my C#. I'll post the code below but it might be easier to skip to the part in the video that I am talking about.

At 6:50 in the video where they start to build out an initMediaSession method is where I'm getting stuck. Especially at the mSession.SetCallback part. I don't know how C# would do the overloaded methods below there and also I haven't been able to get mSession.SetCallback(new MediaSession.Callback(){} to not error out.

The main error I'm getting is "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'MediaSession.Callback'"

Or if you have a better strategy for getting media controls onto an android lock screen then let me know. Thank you.

```
private void initMediaSession()
        {
            DabPlayer dabPlayer = new DabPlayer(true);

            mSession = new MediaSession(Application.Context, "example player sesion");
            mController = new Android.Media.Session.MediaController(Application.Context, mSession.SessionToken);

            mSession.SetCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onPlay() {
                SuperSocket.onPlay();
                buildNotification(generateAction(Android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE));
                }

                @Override
                public void onPause()
                {
                SuperSocket.onPlay();
                buildNotification(generateAction(Android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play", ACTION_PLAY));
                }

                @Override
                public void onSkipToNext()
                {
                SuperSocket.onPlay();
                buildNotification(generateAction(Android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFastForward()
                {
                super.onFastFoward();
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewind()
                {
                super.onRewind();
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewind()
                {
                super.onStop();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStop()
                {
                super.onStop();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicaitonContext().getSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
                notificationManager.Cancel(1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
                stopService(intent);
                }

        });
```

Comment: you need to create your own class that inherits from MediaSession.Callback - see https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/MediaBrowserService/MediaBrowserService/MusicService.cs

Comment: sorry @Jason  I just saw you replied exactly the same thing in a much more concised fashion :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Didn't notice that at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to translate anything, you just have to implementing the existing `MediaSession.Callback` interface.

```
class MediaSessionCallback : MediaSession.Callback
{
    public Action OnPlayImpl { get; set; }

    public Action<long> OnSkipToQueueItemImpl { get; set; }

    public Action<long> OnSeekToImpl { get; set; }

    public Action<string, Bundle> OnPlayFromMediaIdImpl { get; set; }

    public Action OnPauseImpl { get; set; }

    public Action OnStopImpl{ get; set; }

    public Action OnSkipToNextImpl{ get; set; }

    public Action OnSkipToPreviousImpl{ get; set; }

    public Action<string, Bundle> OnCustomActionImpl { get; set; }

    public Action<string, Bundle> OnPlayFromSearchImpl { get; set; }

    public override void OnPlay ()
    {
        OnPlayImpl ();
    }

    public override void OnSkipToQueueItem (long id)
    {
        OnSkipToQueueItemImpl (id);
    }

    public override void OnSeekTo (long pos)
    {
        OnSeekToImpl (pos);
    }

    public override void OnPlayFromMediaId (string mediaId, Bundle extras)
    {
        OnPlayFromMediaIdImpl (mediaId, extras);
    }

    public override void OnPause ()
    {
        OnPauseImpl ();
    }

    public override void OnStop ()
    {
        OnStopImpl ();
    }

    public override void OnSkipToNext ()
    {
        OnSkipToNextImpl ();
    }

    public override void OnSkipToPrevious ()
    {
        OnSkipToPreviousImpl ();
    }

    public override void OnCustomAction (string action, Bundle extras)
    {
        OnCustomActionImpl (action, extras);
    }

    public override void OnPlayFromSearch (string query, Bundle extras)
    {
        OnPlayFromSearchImpl (query, extras);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var mediaCallback = new MediaSessionCallback ();

mediaCallback.OnPlayImpl = () => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "play");

};

mediaCallback.OnSkipToQueueItemImpl = (id) => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "OnSkipToQueueItem:" + id);

};

mediaCallback.OnSeekToImpl = (pos) => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "onSeekTo:", pos);

};

mediaCallback.OnPlayFromMediaIdImpl = (mediaId, extras) => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "playFromMediaId mediaId:", mediaId, "  extras=", extras);

};

mediaCallback.OnPauseImpl = () => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "pause. current state=" + playback.State);

};

mediaCallback.OnStopImpl = () => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "stop. current state=" + playback.State);

};

mediaCallback.OnSkipToNextImpl = () => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "skipToNext");

};

mediaCallback.OnSkipToPreviousImpl = () => {

};

mediaCallback.OnCustomActionImpl = (action, extras) => {

};

mediaCallback.OnPlayFromSearchImpl = (query, extras) => {
    LogHelper.Debug (Tag, "playFromSearch  query=", query);

};
```

Luckily for you, there is even a sample for the implementation of a music service:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/MediaBrowserService/MediaBrowserService/MusicService.cs